# AM Slider extension magento

Tags: magento-1.9

i am using luxury magento theme, magento version is 1.9.0.1,all features are working fine only AM slider extension not working when i click manage slider tab it show empty page. kindly help.

Comment: You might try [magento.stackexchange.com](https://magento.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. After checking your logs it looks like you need PDO on your server.

extension=pdo.so extension=pdo_mysql.so

Ask hosting company or try to turn on this for your own.

2. Second thing that help is to apllay patches from Magento 1.9.2 directory that you have.

Its work I cheked !